Mobile data speed is capped at 64 kB/s
I recently upgraded my phone to android 13 and after the upgrade the mobile connection speed is very slow. On average it doesn't exceed 64 kilobytes per second.
Some information about the phone that most likely don't matter:

It's a Xiaomi Redmi 4X
I'm using Voltage OS 2.8 which builds on Android 13
Previously I used Havoc OS 3 on Android 10, but this is too old now. Mobile data speed worked fine.

Yes, I still got mobile data volume. And if not I would be capped to 56 kilobits per second. Yes I tested it over multiple days.
What could cause this problem? Is there a secret setting for capping mobile speed that might be set? How could I debug this problem?
Did I forget any important information?
Edit on 2024-09-30
I flashed other custom ROMs, I flashed all official stock ROMs, I flashed new firmware, I flashed old firmware, I flashed every available official firmware, nothing changed anything. Even with every official stock ROM, the download speed is capped to 64 kB/s. Then I flashed Lineage 21 and gave up. Some time later the mobile data stopped completely. I had to permit apps to ignore the data saver. The data saver is disabled and always was disabled but permitting apps to ignore a disabled data saver did the trick. I got mobile data again and for about 50% of the time it goes over 64 kB/s. Sometimes it's throttled again for some hours, then it works fine for some hours. This whole behavior is just strange and I'm giving up now.
Edit on 2024-10-30
The mobile data did not go over 64kB/s again.
I bought a new phone, the mobile data is still capped to 64kB/s. I bought a new SIM card, the mobile data is still capped to 64kB/s. If I insert a friends SIM card, it works fine, if I insert my SIM card into other phones, it works fine. May this be a curse? What ingredients do I need to get rid of this? Holy water, sulfur, a crucifix?

64KB/sec is a strange speed. Assuming the ROM has problems with LTE and only can use 2G/3G the speed doesn't fit to any cellular technology like GPRS, EDGE, LTE. Are you sure that you have used up the transfer data included in your data plan? In some countries it is common that the connection is throttled to 64KB/sec once you data plan limit is exceeded.

I am sure I haven't used up the transfer data in my data plan. I got 250 MB (50% :D) remaining. It also shows LTE+ in the status bar. In my country it's common that the connection is throttled to 56 kbit/s once the data plan limit is exceeded

Have you checked the APN configuration? May be the configuration broke or was overwritten by the update. Check the recommended APN settings provided by your MNO and recreate the APN setting.

Indeed I checked the APN configuration. I also created a new one with the settings of my provider (eplus). It didn't change anything. But if the APN configuration would be wrong, I wouldn't get any mobile data, right?

Could my phone "think" that my transfer data is used up and limit the mobile data speed to 64 kB/s because it "thinks" that my provider would throttle it to 64 kB/s? This whole feature would not make sense at all, but I'm grasping at straws here.

If multiple phones are affected then you have to talk to your MNO eplus/O2 (assuming the new phone was used without migrating your data and apps to it, otherwise defect settings may have been migrated, too). Or simply consider terminate your current contract and get a new one, migrating only the phone number to the new contract (a bit like a factory reset for the cellular contract).

Yes, the new phone was set up without migration something. Ii also talked to my provider, they it's hard to find someone with technical knowledge. Thanks for the replies, but I don't want to investigate further at the moment. Too timecomsuming
